# Pourquoi utilise-t-on un ordinal uniquement pour le premier du mois ?

Tags: usage, nombres, indications-de-temps, origine-ou-raison

En français, nous disons :

> le *premier* novembre, puis le deux, trois, quatre, etc.

mais pas :

> le *second*, *troisième*, etc. novembre

Y a-t-il une raison à cet usage exclusif de l'ordinal pour le premier jour du mois ?

Comment: @F'x: Bonne idée de relancer la question, un petit historique sur *premier* et *as* serait le bienvenu.

Comment: En espagnol, cette particularité existe aussi mais seulement dans certains usages : http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/what-is-the-correct-way-to-say-the-days-of-a-month

Comment: /!\ il n'y a pas de second (jour de) novembre, car il y en a 28 autres derrière!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On utilisait autrefois l'ordinal pour tous les jours du mois, je pense en continu depuis le latin vulgaire. La substitution du cardinal s'est effectuée progressivement aux alentours du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Une théorie classique (Sneyders de Vogel, 1934, ch. IV §57 p. 33) y voit l'influence de l'imprimerie :

> Au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle on constate que le cardinal tend à remplacer l'ordinal devant les dates, les chapitres d'un livre, les noms de rois, etc. C'est sans doute l'imprimerie qui en est cause: le fait qu'on écrivait Jules III a fait que dans la prononciation on a remplacé Jules troisième par Jules trois. Les combinaisons avec premier ont pu se maintenir, grâce à leur emploi fréquent.

Une autre hypothèse que j'avance est que *deux*, *trois*, etc., sont des troncatures de l'ordinal correspondant *deuxième*, *troisième*, etc., ce qui en fait naturellement des formes abrégées. Ce phénomène ne permet pas de passer de *premier* à *un*.

La théorie de l'influence de l'imprimerie a toutefois été contestée (Ringenson, 1934). Je n'ai pas trouvé d'analyse moderne sur le sujet.

L'évolution elle-même, en tous cas, est bien attestée par l'usage. Les grammairiens du XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle  (de la Touche, 1737, p. 142 (*Date*)).

> Les sentiments sont fort partagés à l'égard de la date des mois. On dit, par exemple, *le sept Mars*, *le dix Octobre*, &c. ou *le sept de Mars*, *le dix d'Octobre*, &c. ou enfin, *le septième de Mars*, *le dixième d'Octobre*, &c. Les deux premières expressions sont les moins bonnes ; mais elles se permettent, dans les plaidoyers et dans les lettres, pour abréger. Les Historiens doivent s'attacher à la dernière, qui est sans contredit la plus exacte, & la plus suivie.

Un ouvrage du XVIII<sup>e</sup> (Mauvillon, 1747, p. 111–112) à l'intention des germanophones et néérlandophones observe une différence entre une forme complète ordinale et une forme abrégée cardinale lorsque le mois est omis ; il ne signale pas de particularité pour le premier.

> Si quelqu'un demande le quantième que nous avons du Mois, il faut répondre par un nombre cardinal, *le trois*, *le quatre*, *le dix*, *le douze* ; *nous avons le six*, *le sept*, *le huit* ; mais si on ajoutoit le mot *Mois* ou *Lune*, il faudroit employer un nombre ordinal, & dire, *le troisième*, *le quatrième*, *le treizième &c. du Mois, de la Lune*. [...] Que si au-lieu du mot *Mois*, on dit seulement le nom propre des *Mois*, il faut tout de même employer un nombre ordinal, Ex. *le treizième de Janvier*, *le quatrième d'Août*.

Une autre théorie sur l'usage de *premier* est que l'[on évitait autrefois le nombre *un* dans les énumérations](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?t=6917) à cause d'une superstition ; on disait *empreu, deux, trois, etc.*

Au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, on n'utilisait plus que le cardinal sauf pour le premier, le second et dans quelques documents officiels. *Littré* écrit ainsi à l'article *mois* :

> Le premier, le second jour du mois, ou, absolument, le premier, le second du mois. On dit aussi le deux du mois, et, à partir de ce nombre, on ne se sert plus du nombre ordinal, on ne se sert que du nombre cardinal : le trois, le quatre, le douze du mois. Autrefois cet usage n'existait pas ; et l'on disait le troisième, le quatrième, le quinzième, etc. du mois.

Le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française* est du même avis dans sa [huitième édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/mois) (1932) (qui n'a pas changé depuis la cinquième édition de 1798 ; la quatrième édition ne mentionne pas cet aspect) :

> Le premier, le second du mois, le deux, le trois du mois.

Dans la [neuvième édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/mois)

> Le premier, le deuxième jour du mois ou, ellipt., le premier, le deux du mois.

Le phénomène se retrouve dans d'autres langues latines. En portugais, on utilise le cardinal pour les quantièmes de mois, sauf pour le premier jour lorsqu'il est férié: *o dia primeiro de Janeiro*, *o dia um de Fevereiro*. [L'espagnol utilise aussi parfois *primero de enero* plutôt que *uno de enero*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/what-is-the-correct-way-to-say-the-days-of-a-month) (cela dépend des pays).

#### Références

Éléazar de Mauvillon. *Remarques sur les germanismes. Ouvrage utile aux Allemands, aux François, et aux Hollandois, &c*. 1747. [[lien](http://books.google.fr/books?id=-6QGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111)]

Karin Ringenson. *Le rapport d'ordinaux et de cardinaux dans les expressions de la date dans les langues romanes*. E. Droz, 1934. Résumés et critiques : [[lien](http://www.persee.fr/web/revues/home/prescript/article/rbph_0035-0818_1939_num_18_2_1307_t1_0532_0000_2)], [[lien](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00393273508586793#preview)]

K. Sneyders De Vogel. *Syntaxe Historique du français*. 1919. [[lien](http://scans.library.utoronto.ca/pdf/4/28/syntaxehistoriqu00sneyuoft/syntaxehistoriqu00sneyuoft.pdf)], [[lien](http://www.archive.org/stream/syntaxehistoriqu00sneyuoft/syntaxehistoriqu00sneyuoft_djvu.txt)]

N. de la Touche, *L'art de bien parler françois*. 1737. Tome II. [[lien](http://books.google.fr/books?id=mc5DAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142)]

Comment: Merci beaucoup Gilles pour ce résumé clair et super documenté !

Answer (score 8):

Le mot *un* est le plus souvent utilisé en tant qu'article. Peut-être qu'entendre deux articles consécutifs sans savoir immédiatement que le second est en réalité un cardinal est jugé trop distrayant ?

C'est encore plus flagrant ici :

> Hier fut un un novembre ordinaire…

Comment: On dit bien « un Hun, » hein !

Comment: Ceci dit, quand je joue aux dés, je n'ai aucun mal à dire que j'ai fait... un un. Bien qu'on puisse utiliser le terme d'as dans le cas des cartes comme dans celui... des dés.

Comment: Oui, en fin de phrase ça passe facilement, l'intonation change suffisament pour qu'on s'en rende compte. Et l'*as* est peut-être apparu pour la même raison que l'ordinal ?

Answer (score 3):

Il est possible que ce soit en raison des [origines romaines](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendes) du calendrier. Dans ce système, le premier jour du chaque mois, nommé « le calend », avait une significatione particulière.

Answer (score 1):

Il est possible que ce soit une version abrégée du *premier jour du mois de*, à l'instar du *premier de l'an*.

Ça me parait être l'explication la plus raisonnable.

Comment: Pourquoi la même transformation n'a pas eu lieu pour les autres jours ?

Comment: (Désolé, je ne fais que supputer.) Parce qu'il est plus important, non ? Après tout, c'est le premier du mois, un jour de changement !