# Cardinal or ordinal number for kings and queens

Tags: nombres, noms-propres

What kind of numbers should we use in the names of kings and queens : Cardinal or ordinal? I mean, how we must pronounce the name of Henri I, II, III?

Comment: Interestingly similar: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1553/pourquoi-utilise-t-on-un-ordinal-uniquement-pour-le-premier-du-mois

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common usage is cardinal numbers, unless for the first

- François Ier (premier, ordinal)
- Henri IV (quatre, cardinal)

Comment: Why do we use the old form of the ordinal number Quint in the name of Charles Quint? Did the French use ordinal numbers earlier or is it just a set expression?

Comment: "Charles Quint" is definitely a set expression.

Comment: This could be to differentiate Charles V "the Wise" who was a french king, and Charles Quint who was a Holy Roman Emperor, but not a french king

Comment: Here in the title of Charles Quint the ordinal pronoun is used instead of the cardinal pronoun. It is interesting why.

Comment: I have read the article that the French used ordinal numbers in dates about three centuries ago, but now only the first ordinal number is preserved in dates. Maybe something like that was with titles, but I did not manage to find any information about it.