# Chapitre un, chapitre 1 ou chapitre premier

Tags: nombres

Je vois "chapitre premier, tome second..." utilisés dans les livres anciens. La majorité des livres (scientifiques au moins) utilise "chapitre 1, tome 2" qui signifient "chapitre №1, tome №2".

Doit-on (ou bien est-il préférable d') utiliser les nombres ordinaux ou cardinaux pour les chapitres, les tomes, les pages, les sections, etc.?

Un exemple est le livre "Savoir Rédiger : les voies de l'expression française" :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Le gouvernement du Canada présente [un article](https://www.rmc-cmr.ca/fr/escadre-academique/redaction-these) qui détaille abondamment la manière de rédiger une thèse. On y trouve un foisonnement de directives très précises concernant la mise en forme, telle que :

> #### Orthographe et ponctuation
>
> La thèse doit respecter les règles d’orthographe et de ponctuation du français canadien ou international si elle est rédigée en français; ou de l’anglais canadien, britannique ou américain si elle est rédigée en anglais. Le même ensemble de règles doit être utilisé du début à la fin.

Pourtant, à la section qui traite de [la numérotation des chapitres et sections](https://www.rmc-cmr.ca/fr/escadre-academique/redaction-these#num%C3%A9rotation-des-chapitres-et-des-segments), on indique simplement de **suivre son modèle du début à la fin,** en ne fournissant même aucun modèle en exemple :

> #### Numérotation des chapitres et des segments
>
> La numérotation ou le lettrage ainsi que la position des différents niveaux de titre doivent **être constants** tout au long de la thèse.

La numérotation demeure donc très libre selon cette référence.

---

Dans [un autre guide de présentation de textes](http://publications.europa.eu/code/fr/fr-250600.htm), de l’Union européenne cette fois, on présente une gradation possible pour les documents à structure complexe, permettant de distinguer facilement les divers niveaux présents dans le texte :

> Le texte peut être structuré en parties, titres, chapitres, sections, paragraphes, points, etc., en utilisant chiffres, lettres, tirets et puces. Par ordre d’importance décroissante, cette structure de numérotation se présente généralement comme suit:
>
> - des chiffres romains majuscules (I, II, III, IV…),
> - des lettres majuscules (A, B, C, D…),
> - des chiffres arabes (1, 2, 3, 4…),
> - des lettres minuscules (a, b, c, d…),
> - des chiffres romains minuscules (i, ii, iii, iv, v…),
> - des tirets (—),
> - des points en demi-gras (•).

Dans cette configuration, les chapitres sont traités selon le premier niveau présenté, les chiffres romains majuscules. Mais il reste une certaine liberté à l’écrivain, puisque l’on traite juste après du cas où les éléments de la structure du texte ne seraient pas numérotés, mais simplement distingués selon d’autres paramètres (taille et graisse du texte, justification, capitalisation, etc.).

---

On propose aussi à la Banque de dépannage linguistique de l’OQLF, dans le cadre de rédaction scientifique mais à titre d’exemple en passant seulement, le [système](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4697)...

> Premier Chapitre, Chapitre II, Chapitre III

---

Pour une œuvre de fiction ou un essai à structure assez simple, on semble pouvoir faire un peu comme on veut, avec encore plus de liberté que dans des écrits académiques, pédagogiques ou informatifs.

On trouvera divers exemples, tels que *« **Chapitre I<sup>er</sup>, Chapitre II, Chapitre III, etc.** »* dans *Les Trois mousquetaires* d’Alexandre Dumas, plus sobrement *« **I, II, III, etc.** »* dans *Vingt ans après*, suite des *Trois mousquetaires* tout juste cités ou dans *Le Capitaine Fracasse* de Théophile Gautier, et même un exemple de chapitres « **A, B, C, D, etc.** » dans [*L’Histoire sans fin*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Histoire_sans_fin_(roman)) de Michael Ende. *Le Cœur cousu* de Carole Martinez ne numérote pas ses chapitres, se contentant de leur donner un nom, indiqué en gras et capitales : *« **LE PREMIER SANG, LA BOÎTE, etc.** »*. *La vie est ailleurs* de Milan Kundera utilise *« **1, 2, 3, etc.** »*. *Le Hussard sur le toît* de Jean Giono y va avec *« **CHAPITRE PREMIER, CHAPITRE II, CHAPITRE III, etc.** »*

J’ai en mémoire certains exemples de romans où le premier chapitre n’est pas numéroté, la numérotation commençant au chapitre 2. Malheureusement, je n’en ai pas retrouvé d’exemple pour le moment.

Comment: Mais pourquoi "chapitre premier" et pas "premier chapitre" ?

Comment: @BPP «Premier Chapitre» a aussi été mentionné dans la troisième section de la réponse (Banque de dépannage). Néanmoins, votre interrogation est valide en ce sens que la position peut varier, selon un processus qui m'échappe pour l'instant.

Comment: @BPP Un sujet qui s'en approche, avec une très belle réponse acceptée: [ordinal ou cardinal](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1553/13100). Les chapitres sont traités un peu à la manière des souverains et papes. Ça n'explique pas pourquoi un tel rapprochement, mais le sujet est intéressant.

Answer (score 0):

Au nom de la consistance ou de la logique, l'option se porterait plutôt sur Chapitre 1, puisqu'on dit chapitre 2, 3 ...

Answer (score -1):

Personnellement, je pense que l'utilisation des nombres permet d'obtenir une table des matières plus claire. Maintenant, chacun fait ce qu'il veut :^)

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur le forum Français de StackExchange ! S'il vous plait prennez le temps d'écrire une réponse detaillées et/ou avec des sources de manière à réellement répondre à l'utilisateur. Pour plus de détails voir [Ecrire une réponse detaillée](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Notez la section **"Commenter"** est à privilégier dans le doute, une réponse d'une seule ligne a plus sa place dans la section "commentaires" . Si vous avez la moindre question n'hésitez pas à demander je serais heureux de fournir plus de renseignements! Sur ce, bonne journée ! :)

Answer (score -1):

Effectivement il est possible de dire chapitre premier ou tome second. Mais comme tu l'as si bien souligné ça fait ancien. Cela témoigne d'un niveau de langue plus soutenu.

Chapitre 1 / tome 2 pour le suivi dans la table des matières ou dans le titrage c'est plus adapté aujourd'hui.

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur le forum Français de StackExchange ! S'il vous plait prennez le temps d'écrire une réponse detaillées et/ou avec des sources de manière à réellement répondre à l'utilisateur. Pour plus de détails voir [2crire une réponse detaillée](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Notez la section **"Commenter"** est à privilégier dans le doute, une réponse d'une seule ligne a plus sa place dans la section "commentaires" . Si vous avez la moindre question n'hésitez pas à demander je serais heureux de fournir plus de renseignements! Bonne journée !